# how to replace some character with certain repeting regex

Tags: javascript, regex

this is the log

```
console.log(duckShoot(4, 0.64, '|~~2~~~22~2~~22~2~~~~2~~~|'));
```

the output must be====>|~~X~~~X2~2~~22~2~~~~2~~~|

here the code i've try:

```
function duckShoot(ammo, aim, ducks) {

    let shot = Math.floor(ammo * aim)

    // console.log(shot);

    return ducks.replace (/2/g, "X")
}
```

how to make `/2/g` just replace certain repeating

i wanna make code above same function with this

function duckShoot(ammo, aim, ducks) {

```
let shot = Math.floor(ammo * aim)

// console.log(shot);

for (let i = 1; i <= shot; i++) {

    ducks = ducks.replace("2", "X");

}

return ducks
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
let c = 2;   // how many you want to replace
'|~~2~~~22~2~~22~2~~~~2~~~|'.replaceAll('2', o => (c-- >= 0) ? 'X':o )
```

or you can keep the 'old' replace with the regex

```
'|~~2~~~22~2~~22~2~~~~2~~~|'.replace(/2/g, o => (c-- >= 0) ? 'X':o )
```

whereas

```
(o) => (c-- >= 0) ? 'X':o
```

is a simple function decreasing the counter and returning an 'X' or keep the o(riginal)

Comment: the thing that i dont get it is c-- >= 0, what is the meaning of that  ?

i got the answer when  o => (shot-- > 0) ? 'X':o 

not >=, but just >

where the different ?

Comment: if (c-- >= 0)   is equivalent to    if (c >= 0) { c=c-1; ....)
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Decrement